Ad failed to load: No fill
Here’s the updated version with your addition:

My app used to display ads without any issues. However, after a 29-day suspension, my AdMob account was reactivated on October 17, 2024. Since then, real ads have not been displaying in my app.
I’ve reviewed relevant documentation and discussions in the Google Community, and it seems that waiting might be necessary for ads to start appearing again. However, I couldn’t find a clear answer regarding how long this process might take.
Currently, my app shows test ads when using test mode with real ad unit IDs, but real ads are not being served.
I’ve already confirmed that there are no issues with the Policy Center, payment verification, eCPM, or my implementation.
Could someone provide clarity on how long it typically takes for ads to start serving again after account reactivation? Thank you!



